# Reading from a text file to an array in a sorting program

Tags: c++

I am creating a sorting program that contains Selection, Insertion, and Bubble Sorts. So far, I am successful enough to create the program and input the value from the user.

But I want to use a text file to input and store the values to the array instead of user entering the value. I tried multiple times putting the input from text file feature in the program but got no success.

Please have a look at my code in the links below. I would really appreciate if you guys can help me on this.

Thanks

- [Here's my original program **without** the input from text file
  feature.](https://snipsave.com/nathanrossvelt/#/snippet/9ulJTqgzrDJ8hQSVvp)
- [Here's my new modified code **with** the input text file feature](https://snipsave.com/nathanrossvelt/#/snippet/ZXG3MHAgGKdS3s58YA).

Comment: Try to read about how to read file in C++. There are few headers available for this.

Comment: Can you please State, what is your specific error with this? „It does not work“ doesn‘t help in understanding your point...

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Include your code and input in the question at text (indented by 4-spaces so it formats correctly). Don't post links to them -- they could be gone tomorrow. Not to mention I'm not enabling javascript for some site called snipsave...

Comment: Please post the relevant code sections (i.e. the accept function) in your question and not as links.

Answer (score 0):

In this Method:
    void accept(int Arr[], int s)

You are reading to the array using capital I as index. But that variable seems to not be declared.

```
int Index = 0;
While(!file.eof()) {
    file >> Arr[Index];
    Index++;
}
```

Beside that, you may want to pass the length of the Array to the accept-Funktion, to avoid to read to it while exceeding it‘s length.
Also you may want to close the file input stream explicically after you finished reading, just for good code style and readability.

Comment: @Thysce - Can you please elaborate the whole syntax? The loop has gone mad and not stopping.